# How to print list of numbers but counting in like a pyramid fashion in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a loop that prints numbers exactly like this:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I already have this pattern down for different characters, and can even print this:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

But I'm having a big headache trying to figure out how I can make it count. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have to print the list above:

```
for row in range (number_of_rows + 1):
    for column in range(row)
         print (row, end='')
print()
```

Comment: You have a typo

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I was just going to make a comment, but this will be easier:

```
for row in range (number_of_rows + 1):
  for column in range(row)
       print (column+1, end='') #<-- put column here instead of row and add a "+1"
  print()
```

Some more details of what is going on:

```
for row in range (number_of_rows + 1):
```

Iterate from zero to number_of_rows. e.g. if number of rows was 5 this would iterate through a row of 0,1,2,3,4,5

```
for column in range(row):
```

For each row iterate from 0 to the row number minus 1. e.g. row 3 would iterate through 0, 1, 2

```
print (row+1, end='')
```

Print the column, one digit at a time. To start the row at 1 we need to add 1

Comment: hey, thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of this lol, kinda obvious. Maybe I don't fully understand the logic of this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could do something like

```
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
  print(''.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i + 1)))
```

outputs:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```